# What to call an object which is in motion but not accelerating?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, terminology, velocity

I began learning about acceleration and according to the source i learned from an object only accelerates when there is change in vel. &/ direction... what i am wondering is what do you call it when the object does not accelerate?
i.e. when the object travels at a constant speed and direction.

Comment: "*the object travels at a constant speed and direction*" - Relative to what? How about relative to the walls inside an elevator that happens to be in a free fall? Or how about relative to the building, in which this elevator is? The answers obviously would not be the same. So your question is too ambiguous for a correct answer while the answer you've accepted is incorrect.

Comment: @safesphere, if it has constant velocity in any inertial frame, it has constant velocity in all inertial frames. It's fairly common to assume we're measuring these things in an inertial frame if it hasn't been explicitly stated otherwise.

Comment: @ThePhoton One can assume nothing on this site. Besides, when was the last time you were in an inertial frame ;)

Comment: @safesphere Are you saying my answer is incorrect just because the OP didn't list certain assumptions, or is there actually something wrong? On this site I try to be helpful based on what I think the intent and level of the OP is rather than nit pick at every single detail, but if there really is something actually incorrect please let me know so I can make the proper edits.

Comment: @AaronStevens It is OK for the OP to make mistakes and omissions. It is not OK for the person answering a question for the whole world to see to take it lightly and make the answer ambiguous and blurry. You should have explained that motion is relative, the abstraction of inertial frames, how we deal with gravity in real life frames (e.g. see my elevator example above), and so on. Instead your post sounds like you don't really want to go through the trouble. It's not an incorrect answer, it's not really an answer at all and should've been just a comment instead.

Comment: @safesphere I am not trying to be lazy. It's like if someone were to ask what the area of a circle is, I would not go into discussing area integrals in polar coordinates. If someone was asking a projectile motion problem I would not go into how a constant gravitational force is actually an approximation and start discussing GR. This question is more on terminology than about reference frames themselves, so I answered accordingly. If you think my answer is not sufficient, then please make your own. I see where you are coming from, and it would make a great answer from another perspective.

Comment: @AaronStevens There's a great deal of flexibility in any field and different people act differently within reason. When someone is pushing the envelope too much, it prompts a criticism by others. There is a great range of how detailed the answer can be, but there are reasonable limits. For example, if you wrote the GR equations in your answer, it also would prompt a criticism of the answer bringing too much unnecessary detail. So it does go both ways. In this case I feel that you your answer did not pass the minimum threshold of reasonable details. It wouldn't hurt mentioning relative motion.

Comment: @safesphere I see what you are saying. Thanks for the tips. I'll add an edit.

Comment: @safesphere I was thinking of a 2D space, so basically point A to point B and you have an object that has a constant speed while traveling from A to B

Comment: @IdontReallywolf Speed is relative. You object's speed is measured constant to what? For example, distance is also relative. You cannot say "my distance" without saying, distance to what. When you sit in a chair watching TV, your distance relative to the TV is constant, but the Earth rotates at roughly a thousand miles per hour, so your distance to the Sun or Moon is rapidly changing during this time. The same with the speed. Your speed relative to the TV is a constant zero, but relative to the Sun you're wildly rotating with the Earth. There are no points in space like A and B, only objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you call the object anything. You might hear people use the phrase "uniform motion". Although this term can also be applied to circular motion as "uniform circular motion" which is motion in a circle with a constant speed, but like you said there is still acceleration due to a direction change.

So I would say "uniform motion", "uniform linear motion", "motion under $0$ acceleration", or maybe just "constant velocity". Maybe other people know some things I haven't heard of or thought of though.

---

It should be mentioned that this all depends on the reference frame you are observing the object in. All motion is relative, so you need to first specify your frame of reference. For example, a ball in free fall will appear at rest to someone falling along with the ball, but to an observer on the Earth the motion of the ball will not be uniform linear motion. Since you made minimal assumptions, I just stuck with a simple answer. If the object is observed from an inertial (non-accelerating) frame, then we will see uniform linear motion in all inertail frames.

Comment: *uniform linear motion*?

Comment: Isn't this an inertial frame of reference.  From Wiki; An inertial frame of reference in classical physics and special relativity is a frame of reference in which a body with zero net force acting upon it is not accelerating; that is, such a body is at rest or it is moving at a constant speed in a straight line

Comment: @foolishmuse I am not sure about this. You can be in an inertial frame of reference without referring to the motion of an object. And you can have an object undergoing acceleration observed from an inertial frame of reference. I see where you are coming from though.

Comment: @foolishmuse Maybe it could be **inertial motion** but practically we haven't adopted this usage in English physics terminology. Fun fact, in Turkish, we sometimes use counterpart of *inertial motion* (eylemsiz hareket) but dominantly the ones in Aaron's answer.

Comment: A rest frame need not be an inertial one. For example, an accelerating object has a rest frame... but that frame isn't inertial since, when viewed from that accelerating object's frame, inertial objects won't travel in straight lines with constant velocity. Example: a car that is suddenly braking.

Comment: @OktayDoğangün  I'm always big on creating new words. So I'm starting SAIM.  Society for the Adoption of Inertial Motion.  And "saim" pronounced "same" even sounds right for the topic at hand!

Answer (score 0):

"**inertial motion**".

that's what i would call it.